# Free cross-platform 3D world generator

Tags: linux, windows-7, 3d, game-development

I used to have a free 3D world platform generator when I was a Windows guy, that was a long time ago and I forgot its name.

So I'm a Linux guy, my friend is a Windows guy. We're working on a 3D mobile game. For now we're creating the terrain by hand. I am looking for a 3D world generator or terrain generator or universe generator, call it what you want.

Requirements are:

- Free; not necessarily open source, no stupid licensing that tie your hands.
- Cross-platform, more importantly, the generator has to work on Linux, as I'm the guy working on modeling. Wine is fine. My friend uses Windows 7 64 bit, I use Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.
- Blender support.
- Work on mobile devices.
- Decent 3D rendering quality.
- If I have to do some scripting to generate things, then I prefer Lua or Python or C++.